# Use Jest with @web/test-runner

Tags: jestjs, headless, test-runner, playwright

I am trying to use `@web/test-runner` as my test runner on top of `snowpack`.
So far I am successful with `@web/test-runner-playwright` to launch a headless browser to run my tests.
Now I need a testing framework (i.e. `jest`) to utilize its `test` and `expect` constructs.

How can I use `jest` with the above setup?

I tried to directly import these from `@jest/globals` but I got an error saying `Do not import '@jest/globals' outside of the Jest test environment`, which is understood.

I do not want to use `jest` as my test runner because I want to leverage my `snowpack` pipeline with my tests as well as to run tests in actual headless browser. This is why I am using `@web/test-runner`.

How to integrate `jest` with `@web/test-runner`?

Comment: Seems like the modern-web test runner is a Jest replacement, so you don't need to install Jest there. They do similar things with it/describe/expect. If you want to use their test-runner, then this resources should help: https://modern-web.dev/docs/test-runner/writing-tests/js-tests/ You can also stick e.g. with the official test runner https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-test or use the jest-playwright preset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get it working with [jest-browser-globals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-browser-globals):

```js
const { esbuildPlugin } = require('@web/dev-server-esbuild')

module.exports = {
  nodeResolve: true,
  files: ['src/**/*.spec.{ts,tsx}'],
  plugins: [
    esbuildPlugin({
      ts: true,
      tsx: true,
      jsxFactory: 'h',
      jsxFragment: 'Fragment',
    }),
  ],
  coverageConfig: {
    include: ['src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'],
  },
  testRunnerHtml: testFramework => `
    <html>
      <head>
        <script type="module" src="${testFramework}"></script>
        <script type="module">import 'jest-browser-globals';</script>
      </head>
    </html>
  `,
}
```

This config is using the esbuild plugin for bundling which works pretty fast and I recommend, but you could remove it.

The same tests run in jest (node+jsdom) and web-test-runner in the browser. Debugging and sourcemaps all work pretty well.

Comment: This was very helpful in converting Karma+Jasmine tests over to `@web/test-runner`: Jest `expect()` is very similar to Jasmine `expect()`. One thing to note is that Jest provides both an assertion library (`expect`) and test definition functions (`describe`/`it`/`beforeAll`/etc), while jest-browser-globals provides *only the assertion library*. Jest globals such as `beforeAll` will not be made available, because those are specific to the test runner. In `@web/test-runner`, Mocha is in place for `describe`/`it`/`before`/etc. Be sure to check your test runner for the test definition functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to go is to setup a [custom runner](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#runner-string) in the jest config. If I get something working I will post it here!

Answer (score -2):

Dont use Jest unless you have very specific requirement. Jest doesn't fully support ECMAScript Modules. And as you are using modern web provided tools, I assume that you will be interested in using ECMAScript latest versions. You can read more about it here- https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules

You can use mocha + chai combination with web test runner. You can refer this setup from here - https://github.com/snowpackjs/snowpack/tree/main/create-snowpack-app/app-template-react-typescript

Comment: The OP isn't using Jest as a test runner, and Jest's (in)compatibility with ES modules isn't really relevant here. The mocha + chai combination presents a pretty limited API compared to the Jest `expect` API; the OP wants to take advantage o that.